# Perl (SSH to remote host, Issues the command and close the session without waiting it to finish...)

Tags: perl, scripting, ssh

Script goes to the remote server and runs a shell script "snap.sh" using Net::SSH::Perl. 
This shell script takes almost 10mins to end, and my perl program waits until it gets output.
I want to run the shell script on the remote sever and the program should close the SSH session without waiting for the script to finishes on the remote server.

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host, protocol =>2);
$ssh->login($username, $password);
my $cmd="./bin/snap.sh";
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but can't you just do what `ssh -f` does?

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host, protocol =>2);
$ssh->login($username, $password);
defined (my $pid = fork) or die "fork: $!";
if ($pid) {
    close $ssh->sock;
    undef $ssh;
} else {
    my $cmd="./bin/snap.sh";
    my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
    POSIX::_exit($exit);
}
```

Comment: Not working same issue, program does not exits..waiting to get some status from remote server

Comment: @Xomo: What is your platform?  If it's Windows, `fork` emulation is problematic and could cause that.

Comment: ...Thanks a lot , I am sorry I just made one mistake last time around... Could you please explain a little bit ..what is the concept behind it...?

Comment: This still leaves a new process running on the local host until the remote job finishes.

Answer (score 4):

Lookup the `nohup` command. Here is [quick post to get you started](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html). For completeness here is what should work in your case...

```
my $cmd="nohup ./bin/snap.sh &";
```

Comment: Andrew, I tried this. It is running the cmd in the background on the remote server but the session is not closed..it is still waiting. I guess it had lot to do with NET::SSH::Perl module

Comment: You'll still need to logout/exit to end the session. I assumed that was simply omitted from the question.

Comment: my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
At this command the script stops and wait for the remote command to end....

Answer (score 1):

To run a background job on a remote host, you also need to dissociate from any controlling ttys on the local machine. Try a command like:

```
my $cmd = "./bin/snap.sh < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 &";
```

I think using `nohup` is optional.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.50/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm#spawn) for this. It has a *spawn* method that does exactly what you're looking for.

```
  my %conn = map { $_ => Net::OpenSSH->new($_) } @hosts;
  my @pid;
  for my $host (@hosts) {
      open my($fh), '>', "/tmp/out-$host.txt"
        or die "unable to create file: $!";
      push @pid, $conn{$host}->spawn({stdout_fh => $fh}, $cmd);
  }

  waitpid($_, 0) for @pid;
```